# Google Maps API ban?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

My website (http://foomap.de/), which features a fullscreen map via Google Maps API v3, suddenly stopped working today. Instead it presents the error message 
"Google has disabled the use of Maps API for this application. See terms of Service for more information: http://www.google.com/help/terms_maps.html"

I'm neither aware of any violations of google's terms of service nor did the website reach any   usage limits (according to Google's API console).

Any ideas what is wrong?

Comment: Please search.  There are at least 2 other questions of this exact nature within the last hour.

Comment: Today we experienced a temporary outage on a number of sites using the Google Maps JavaScript API. We’re aware of the issue and have rolled out a fix.

Answer (score 0):

assuming there are no other problems, you have a daily and per-second limit.  You may be over quota.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to be a google error on their end...

http://www.google.com.au/about/jobs/locations/sydney/

Answer (score 0):

For now, remove the key parameter as its not a mandatory:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=SET_TO_TRUE_OR_FALSE">
</script>
```

It worked for me, but i still don't know why whats the problem.. I believe Google is doing some changes...